# compare two collection in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I have two different collection book and music in JSON .First I give a book collection example:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("b1"),
    "author" : [
        "Mary",
    ],
    "title" : "Book1",
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("b2"),
        "author" : [
            "Joe",
            "Tony",
            "Mary"
        ],
        "title" : "Book2",
}
{
            "_id" : ObjectId("b3"),
            "author" : [
                "Joe",
                "Mary"
            ],
            "title" : "Book3",
}
.......
```

Mary writes 3 books, Joe write 2 books, Tony writes 1 book. Second I give a music collection example:

```
 {
        "_id" : ObjectId("m1"),
        "author" : [
            "Tony"
        ],
        "title" : "Music1",
    }
    {
            "_id" : ObjectId("m2"),
            "author" : [
                "Joe",
                "Tony"
            ],
            "title" : "Music2",
    }
    .......
```

Tony has 2 musics, Joe has 1 music, Mary has 0 music.

I hope to get the number of authors who write more books than music.

Thus, Mary(3 > 0) and Joe(2 > 1) should take into consideration, but not Tony(1 < 2). Thus the final result should be 2(Mary and Joe).

I write down following code, but don't know how to compare:

```
db.book.aggregate([ 
     { $project:{ _id:0, author:1}},
     { $unwind:"$author" },     
     {$group:{_id:"$author", count:{$sum:1}}}  
     ]
     )

db.music.aggregate([ 
     { $project:{ _id:0, author:1}},
     { $unwind:"$author" },     
     {$group:{_id:"$author", count:{$sum:1}}}  
     ]
     )
```

Is it so far right? How to do the following comparison? Thanks.

Comment: Is this [also your account](http://stackoverflow.com/users/5862094/cacao) or do the two of you possibly work together? This is almost an [exact duplicate of this now deleted question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36671480/how-to-compare-between-two-collections-in-mongodb) where the only difference is naming one collection `"music"` ( for some strange reason ) other than `"paper"` as it was originally there. As was commented originally, this is really just "looping results" to compare. If you want something more performant, then put all data in "one" collection instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to solve that problem, we need to use $out phase and store result of both queries in intermediate collection and then use aggregated query to join them ($lookup).

```
db.books.aggregate([{
            $project : {
                _id : 0,
                author : 1
            }
        }, {
            $unwind : "$author"
        }, {
            $group : {
                _id : "$author",
                count : {
                    $sum : 1
                }
            }
        }, {
            $project : {
                _id : 0,
                author : "$_id",
                count : 1
            }
        }, {
            $out : "bookAuthors"
        }
    ])

db.music.aggregate([{
            $project : {
                _id : 0,
                author : 1
            }
        }, {
            $unwind : "$author"
        }, {
            $group : {
                _id : "$author",
                count : {
                    $sum : 1
                }
            }
        }, {
            $project : {
                _id : 0,
                author : "$_id",
                count : 1
            }
        }, {
            $out : "musicAuthors"
        }
    ])

db.bookAuthors.aggregate([{
            $lookup : {
                from : "musicAuthors",
                localField : "author",
                foreignField : "author",
                as : "music"
            }
        }, {
            $unwind : "$music"
        }, {
            $project : {
                _id : "$author",
                result : {
                    $gt : ["$count", "$music.count"]
                },
                count : 1,
            }
        }, {
            $match : {
                result : true
            }
        }
    ])
```

> EDIT CHANGES:
>
> used author field instead of _id
>
> added  logical statement embeded in document in $project phase
>
> result : { $gt : ["$count", "$music.count"]

Any questions welcome!
Have a fun!

Comment: Hi, I follow your suggestion, and meet some problem, and write it down in your answer, Thanks!

Comment: I just need to get the number of author who write more book the music, so , do I need to add ｛$group:_id:null, number:{$sum:1}｝after $match? is it right?